# In which cases does a sql update statement return as no rows updated?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

In my application we are using the following code

```
if (m_ps.executeUpdate() != 1) {
             {
                    throw new ConcurrentDBModificationException();
                }
            }
}
```

The table we are updating is present for sure.

Also the table has a timestamp colomn which gets filled up correctly.

It just happens on some customers environment which i cannot debug.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Need to see the executeUpdate method at and anything else in the call stack that is relevant.

Comment: Your application will hurl `ConcurrentDBModificationException()` if your method `m_ps.executeUpdate()` returns anything other than 1.  You seem to be assuming it is returning `0` but it could be returning `2`.  Or `200`.  How can we tell?  We can't see the source code.  You haven't provided nearly enough details.  Please edit your question with more information if you want us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The following is case where an sql update statement will return as no rows updated :

UPDATE employees SET salary = 14 WHERE age > 40

...basically when there are no rows that are returned by the WHERE clause.

**EDIT**

Considering the "throw ConcurrentDBModificationException()", this is probably in the case where the edited row has been deleted from the table while the user was using your application to edit the information...

Comment: eh?  what's this supposed to be?

Comment: an sql update statement where where could be zero affected lines

Comment: Any `UPDATE` statement can affect zero rows on a table with zero rows, posting random SQL without explanation as to what it means is not an answer.